# Filtering path with Regex

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

I'm working on a web service that have a regex as its path: `@Path("{hash: .*}")` however, this matches everything; and that it makes other servlet in-accessible (at least those that are not JAX-RS).

I need to filter specific path that it won't process, path like `"_ah/admin/datastore*"` anyone can help out?

Comment: What is the character range of hash ? Can you use this `{hash: [a-zA-Z_0-9]+}` or something like that ?

Comment: Sounds like a nice catch. However I actually needed to catch invalid path request like '/foo/bar/foo.jpg' where the resource that handles this @Path{"hash: .*") returns something when this occurs, rather than showing the Jax-RS "Could not find path relative to resource: "

Comment: I mean this is the reason I am catching everything, the good thing with JAX-RS anything mapped with @Path get passed this 'catch-all' regex, so they still get served. The problem is really with plain servlets they don't get served....

Comment: Would it be possible to map plain servlets with `context/_servlets/path` so the regex does not pick them ?

Comment: can you set up an `@ApplicationPath` for jax-rs servlets separating them from plain servlets? which jax-rs - version are you operating on ?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0-beta-3, '@ApplicationPath' looks like a neat approach...